I have imported an existing ipynb file into an Azure Python notebook . There are errors in importing libraries while running the computer
I have imported an existing ipynb file into an Azure notebook. And trying to run using Azure computers.
In the libraries import section, I get the errors those given below:
from sksurv.linear_model import CoxPHSurvivalAnalysis
from sksurv.util import Surv

I have taken the below steps:

pip install Cmake (PyPI)
pip install scikit-survival (PyPI)

still it is showing errors in import libraries like above.
I am expecting to fix the errors in the libraries.

You haven't included the error messages that you're seeing.
